# I want to work on Android Studio but with no internet connection.Is that possible?

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried but always get error of junit. I have to remove the junit test compile from the build.gradle
Let me make it more clear . I want to run the project offline fully.I have the latest Android Studio 2.0 and SDk fully updated now I want to make projects offline. I don't have net access. I want to work offline and make projects offfline.No net to connect once at the start also.

Comment: it shouldn't matter as long as its not the first run

Comment: Can you please define what you are asking? This is unclear. Can you post the unit test and the affected code and what the exact problem is?

Comment: Its the first run.

Comment: Let me make it more clear . I want to run the project offline fully.I have the latest Android Studio 2.0 and SDk fully updated now I want to make projects offline. I don't have net access. I want to work offline and make projects offfline.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have JUnit cached locally to be able to use it in offline mode. Run the tests at least once while being online, so that Gradle is able to cache the artefact.

Comment: Sorry I was editing the comment but not able to do.Actually I want to do it offline way I have no internet connection in home so and also in office proxy is there. How to do without internet connection the sync

Answer (score 2):

Please click on app folder in android studio and right clck then

1. Open Module Setting
2. goto dependencies
3. remove junit
4. rebuild.
   done!..

Comment: It solved the error , but is it the right way to do offline . By removing the dependency? PLease explain.

Comment: Sorry but now its giving error in exampleUnitTest.java 
as org.junit not found

Comment: Error:(3, 17) error: package org.junit does not exist